# NodeJS Sublime Text Build System

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

I've installed Sublime Text's NodeJS plugin which provides a NodeJS build that looks like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "shell":true,
  "encoding": "cp1252",  
  "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node", "$file"]
    },
  "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["killall node; node", "$file"]
    }
}
```

I've compiled `node` myself and located into: `/opt/node/v0.10.24`. The full path to the bin being `/opt/node/v0.10.24/bin/node`.

I'm testing this with a simple file containing `console.log('Hello World');`

When running the build system I get:

```
/Users/jviotti/Desktop/test.js: node: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
```

I tried adding a `path` to the build like this:

```
"path": "/opt/node/v0.10.24/bin",
```

And when running the build I get just:

```
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Notice that the console log is not printed. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** This is the NodeJS plugin I use: https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs

Comment: Can you please give a link to the build system you use

Comment: @Zub Added a link at the bottom.

Comment: What you are using is not a NodeJS plugin, it's a native Sublime Text [Build System](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html). Here is a good article of how to start using it: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text . I've made it work with just 2 options: `"cmd"` and `"selector"`. Maybe in your case it didn't work because of `"file_regex"` option

Comment: Is your path `/opt/node/v0.10.24/bin` correct? Maybe `/opt/node-v0.10.24/bin` ?

Comment: @Zub I created another build system for scratch and it worked. This made me investigate more on the NodeJS Build System. Commenting out `shell: true`. Can you provide an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think it's not needed. Glad you've found an answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Commenting out `"shell": true` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it ..

```
{
  "cmd": ["node $file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "shell": false,
  "encoding": "cp1252",
  "windows":
    {
      "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe && node $file"]
    },
  "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["killall nodejs 2>/dev/null; nodejs $file"] // or node, if built from source
    }
}
```